# Build asp net core with grpc, errors: wellknowntype not found

Tags: c#, .net, docker, grpc

I build an asp net core API project with a docker. This project contains some proto files and imports some google well-known types. But I got output errors:

```
- google/protobuf/Timestamp.proto : error : File not found. [/src/mymy/mymy.csproj]
- Protos/notification.proto(4,1): error : Import "google/protobuf/Timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors. [/src/mymy/mymy.csproj]
- Protos/notification.proto(112,5): error : "google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined. [/src/mymy/mymy.csproj]
```

I put my source code in [github](https://github.com/pearl2201/docker-aspnetcore-grpc): https://github.com/pearl2201/docker-aspnetcore-grpc

Answer (score 2):

It is correct... they're not defined; with `Grpc.Tools`, imports still need to exist. You can use the `ProtoRoot` option on the `<Protobuf ...>` line to tell it where the root is, for this purpose. In [BUILD-INTEGRATION](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md) there is also some mention of `$(Protobuf_StandardImportsPath)`, but that seems to refer only to `<ProtoCCommand>`.

(as an aside: the protobuf-net tools include copies of all the common imports inside the package; if they aren't resolved from the file system, it looks to see what it has inside the assembly instead, but: this is not a direct change, as the protobuf-net tools output very different C#, intended for a different library implementation).